# Elastic search painless script issue with long type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

> I am currently using Elastic search 5.2 and trying to perform **upsert** 
>   operation using the following rest api:

- http://ip:9200/indexname/typename/id/_update

  Json Payload:

  ```
  {
  "script" : {
      "inline": "ctx._source.size +=params.size",
      "lang": "painless",
      "params" :{
      "size" : 14889114000
      }
  },
  "upsert" : {
      "size" : 1488911400
  }
  ```

  }

This api does the following things:

1.) If the index is not found in the elastic search then creates an index with the json provided inside the upsert field.
2.) If the index exist then it performs the partial update by running the painless script provided in the document.

Issue: 
I have created the elastic search index mapping for counter as long.
This update works fine until the counter value is within the integer range.(i.e)2,147,483,647
Beyond this value, it overflows and becomes the negative value which in case the expected value it positive long value(as the corresponding index map is long). Is there a way to solve this int overflow issue while using painless script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to modify your script a little bit and not use the `+=` operator. If you modify your script to `ctx._source.size = ctx._source.size + params.size` instead of `ctx._source.size += params.size`, then it will work as you expect:

```
POST indexname/typename/id/_update
{
  "script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.size = ctx._source.size + params.size",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params" :{
      "size" : 14889114000
    }
  },
  "upsert" : {
    "size" : 1488911400
  }
}
```

First the document will be upserted with `size: 1488911400` and then on the second update it will contain the value `size: 16378025400` which is `1488911400 + 14889114000`

Comment: Still i have one more issue. If both the values in the context and the value in the params are int then it still over flows.  i.e if the value in the context is 2147483647 and the value in the param is 2 then it still over flows to the negative value. Any idea how it can be fixed ?